# Datareader issue

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

1)
This is my code to check for username and password and if matches then login.:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOK.Click
    Try
        Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim logQuery As String = ("SELECT * FROM Login_db where Username='" & txtUsername.Text & "'")
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(logQuery, cnnOLEDB)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader              
        If dr.Read = True Then         <-------------------- problem

            If txtUsername.Text = dr("Username") Then
                If txtPassword.Text = dr("Password") Then
                    MsgBox("Hii")
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox("Byee")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

The line `if dr.read=true then` returns false even if i hv records in my table...

2)This is my code to add a new user in the Login table

Try

```
        Dim addUser As String

        addUser = "INSERT INTO Login_db(Username,Password) VALUES (@uname,@pswd)"
        cnnOLEDB.Open()

        Dim _comm As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(addUser, cnnOLEDB)

        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtUsername.Text)
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswd", txtPasswd.Text)
        _comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnnOLEDB.Close()

        MsgBox("Record Inserted", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    End Try
```

Error is : Syntax error in insert into statement.. I am not able to find my error .

plz resolve my problem... Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this is an MS Access database. In that case the word PASSWORD is a reserved keyword.
If you have used that name as column name then you should always encapsulate it with square brackets.

```
addUser = "INSERT INTO Login_db(Username,[Password]) VALUES (@uname,@pswd)"
```

As a side note, your select query to retrieve the user is dangerous and could fail if the user name contains a single quote (apostrophe) or worse could be the vector for a sql injection attack. Use always parametrized query as you do in the insert statement

```
Dim logQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM Login_db where Username=@uname"
cnnOLEDB.Open()
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(logQuery, cnnOLEDB)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtUserName.Text)
```